# Are "productVariant" or "customers" not available on Shopify's checkout query hook?

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I am using `@shopify/ui-extensions-react v2023.7.x` node package. `query` function is under `useApi` hook. I didn't find any doc about how much can I query on `shopify.dev`. Here's my query,

```
query {
  customers(query: "email:john@example.com", first: 1) {
    nodes {
      tags
    }
  }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is,

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field 'customers' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 9
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "query",
        "customers"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "undefinedField",
        "typeName": "QueryRoot",
        "fieldName": "customers"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, is there a limitation because of security or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Checkout Extensions, there it uses Checkout UI extensions API. Here is the documentation for it https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/2023-07/apis

If you need to access Customers of productVariants, you should use [Admin API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin) instead. It seems `useApi` does not support it, so another authentification should be implemented for that.